# C++ 3d game development

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, 3d, xna

I just bought visual studio pro and I want to make video games. I have programmed in Xna, but I want to move on. Is there any c++ 3d game engines for visual studio c++ 2010 pro that is simaler to Xna?

Comment: Please note that XNA is not a Game Engine, it is a framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[OGRE](http://www.ogre3d.org/) is pretty good as well, easy enough to use and well supported. It also comes with a good user community and a good set of tutorials.

Answer (score 4):

The [Irrlicht](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/) Engine is an open source high performance realtime 3D engine written in C++. It is completely cross-platform, using D3D, OpenGL and its own software renderers, and has all of the state-of-the-art features which can be found in commercial 3d engines.